# How to figure out when my hot (but cooling) drinking water will go bad

Tags: limnology

I have a 200 liter electric water heater in a secondary building.
The time periods between me visiting the building and using the water vary and do not follow any schedule.
I can be visiting as rarely as once every 6 months or as often as once every two weeks.
The heater is turned off during periods when I am not at the building to save on electricity, but the heater is well insulated and the water stays warm in the heater for up to two weeks, while slowly cooling down.

The issue is that around 3-4 weeks the water goes bad due to being in the sweet spot for bacteria creation temperature wise (30-40 degrees celsius it seems) for a while.
Then the water starts smelling bad and obviously needs to be discarded, which is wasteful and cumbersome.

**The question**: I want to install a smart plug (and possibly some temperature sensors) to turn on the water heater every once in a while to keep the water from going bad. I want to hit the sweet spot where the water heater is on as little as possible to conserve the most electricity and still keep the water from going bad.

Obviously there is no one perfect answer for this (e.g. "dont allow the water to go below 40 degrees for more than 8 hours and the water will be safe for consumption forever"), as the water contents will be different based on location, filtering setup, etc, but are there any general guidelines on how to approach this? or a way to figure out what the perfect balance would be for my specific setup without resolving to trial-by-error?

I've googled around using "how long does it take for warm water to go bad" query, but this returns results only on how long you need to wait until the water heater reheats cold water, not how long it takes for warm water to go bad.

Reason for me not wanting to go with "just replace with a flow-through kind of water heater instead of tank kind" is this water heater is hooked up to the fireplace of the building (i.e. fireplace warms up pipes with heating water in them that are circulated by a pump through the tank without mixing with the drinking water), and if I am already in the building, I will be running the fireplace and the water in the heaters tank will be heated for me, without needing to use the electrical function of the water heater.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really an answerable Biology question (even though it's about bacteria). As you stated, it somewhat depends on factors we cannot guess at. There are answers, but they don't work for you, so it's more about water temperature regulation, efficiency and personal economical considerations.

Comment: I'd say it's a practical application of theoretical concepts and knowledge of bioligy, but fair enough, I understand why you would think this way. Could you suggest a better stack exchange site to ask this question on rather than bioligy?

Comment: DIY maybe? Home improvement? I don't know. Potential *biological* solutions include keeping the water heater on at 140° all the time/heat the water to 160° for several hours when you return after an absence (hard on the heater, shortens lifespan)/shock chlorinate the tank, hot water pipes (you have to drain off all the sediments first, as it can harbor and protect bacteria insuring you always have a ready supply of contaminants)/get a hot water on demand system/etc. etc. But you will reject them, so it's not really biological at all. Your requirements make it otherwise.